# How to set the width of absolute positioned droppdown menu to fit the longest list item?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a header with 2 dropdowns.
the dropdown menu position is absolute to it's wrapper container. 
I want each dropdown menu width fit to the size of longest list entry. I am wondering if there is any solution without looping through li s and achieve it only using css?

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-dropdownContainer">

    <div class="navdropdown nav-primary__dropdown">
      <div class="navdropdown__text">
        Themes
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">+</i>
      </div>

      <ul class="navdropdown__list">
        <li class="navdropdown__listItem"><a href="">linktheme1</a></li>
        <li class="navdropdown__listItem"><a href="">linktheme2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>


    <div class="navdropdown nav-primary__dropdown">
      <div class="navdropdown__text">
        tags
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">+</i>
      </div>

      <ul class="navdropdown__list">
        <li class="navdropdown__listItem"><a href="">linktag1</a></li>
        <li class="navdropdown__listItem"><a href="">linktag2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

And CSS:

```
ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

nav{
background-color: grey;
line-height: 35px;

}
.nav-dropdownContainer {
height: 70px;
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.navdropdown {
background-color: #455565;
display: inline-block;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
height: 100%; }

.navdropdown:first-child {
border-left: 1px solid #fff; }

.navdropdown > ul {
margin: 0; }

.navdropdown:hover .navdropdown__text {
color: #fff; }

.navdropdown.open .navdropdown__text {
color: #fff; }

.navdropdown.open .navdropdown__list {
display: block; }

.navdropdown .fa-chevron-up,
.navdropdown .fa-chevron-down {
padding-left: 1rem;
font-size: 0.875rem; }

.navdropdown .navdropdown__text {
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
color: #ccc;
border-top: none;
padding: 1rem; }

.navdropdown__list {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
background-color: #455565;
list-style-type: none; }

.navdropdown__list .navdropdown__listItem {
width: 100%;
float: left;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #374350;
margin: 0; }

.navdropdown__list .navdropdown__listItem > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer; }

.navdropdown__list .navdropdown__listItem:hover {
background-color: #374856; }
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  // Cache DOM
  var $body = $('body'),
    $window = $(window),
    _dropdownClassName = '.navdropdown',
    $dropdownContainer = $('.nav-dropdownContainer');


  $body.on('click', _dropdownClassName, toggleDropdown);



  function closeAllDropdowns(){
    $(_dropdownClassName).removeClass('open');
    $('.navdropdown__text i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
  }

  /**
   * toggle dropdown
   */
  function toggleDropdown(){

    const $this = $(this);
    const $thisArrow = $this.find('.navdropdown__text i');

    var leftPosition =  $this.offset().left - $dropdownContainer.offset().left;
    console.log('leftPosition', leftPosition);


    if (window.Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 64em)')) {
      $this.find('.navdropdown__list').css('left', 0);
    }else{
      if(leftPosition > 0){
        $this.find('.navdropdown__list').css('left', leftPosition+'px');
      }
    }


    if($thisArrow.hasClass('fa-chevron-down')){
      closeAllDropdowns();
      $this.addClass('open');
      $thisArrow.removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
    }else{
      closeAllDropdowns();
    }
  }

})();
```

Code Pen link: http://codepen.io/neginbasiri/pen/Xjgwkx

Comment: You can use `max-width` If need an example tell me

Comment: @SAM Can you please show it in the code? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant `min-width` I'll Answer you just a while..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `navdropdown` class : `min-width: 40%;`
It sets the minimum width of them to 40% of it's container width(**If you have more items set this percentage proportional to the number of items**).
If you want it be exactly like the biggest width involves some javascripts I don't recommend that way.